# Docker run fail with quorum

Tags: docker, quorum

Anyone know how to address the issue `"Fatal: Consensus not specified. Exiting!!"` when runing `docker run -it quorumengineering/quorum`?

[image]

Comment: Ask the software owner.

Answer (score -1):

Need to specify genesis.json. Issue solved.